# Android Warning : Grows due to localized text expansion

Tags: android, android-layout, warnings, android-relativelayout, xml-layout

I am getting this type of warning

> @id/order_row_date can overlap @id/order_row_amout if
> @id/order_row_date grows due to localized text expansion.
>
> If relative layout has text or button items aligned to left
> and right sides they can overlap each other due to localized text
> expansion unless they have mutual constraints like toEndOf/toStartOf.

My XML File is:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/order_row_lower_layout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/order_row_upper_layout"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/order_row_box_layout"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/order_row_box_layout"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/order_row_amout"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_normal"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_normal"
            android:textColor="@color/color_gray"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="50000"
            tools:text="@string/string_amout_with_ruppe" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/order_row_date"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textColor="@color/color_gray"
            tools:text="08/09/2016" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Anyone Know about this type of warning?

Appreciated in Advance :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have just changed width of first **`AppCompatTextView`** with `match_parent` and added following two lines:

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/order_row_date"
android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/order_row_date"
```

So Final XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/order_row_lower_layout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/order_row_upper_layout"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/order_row_box_layout"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/order_row_box_layout"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/order_row_amout"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_normal"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_normal"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/order_row_date"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/order_row_date"
        android:textColor="@color/color_gray"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="50000"
        tools:text="@string/string_amout_with_ruppe" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/order_row_date"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="@color/color_gray"
        tools:text="08/09/2016" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Problem Solved in few Mins and It's very easy to understand.

May be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

I used constraint layout to solve this issue. With 0dp for both widths and applying margin as per requirements, Setting proper constraints, This issue won't aris at all.

BTW I got this issue while I was modifying someone's code after a long time.